# RavenDB DeleteByIndex RetrieveDetails

Tags: ravendb

I have a RavenDB Index that I am using to delete a bunch of documents at one time. I would like to know home many documents were actually deleted after the operation is done, however I can't figure out how to get that information from a DatabaseCommands call. For a RavenQuery/DocumentQuery you can use the out Statistics, but I haven't found anything for the DatabaseCommands.

I did find a RetrieveDetails flag as part of the BulkOperationsOptions but I'm not sure how to actually see the details. Here is what my query looks like

```
var op = connection.Store.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(
  "Store/ByExpiration",
  new IndexQuery
  {
    Query = "Expiration:yes"
  },
  new BulkOperationOptions
  {
    AllowStale = false,
    RetrieveDetails = true
  });

op.WaitForCompletion();
```

At this point I am not sure how to get the details once the operation has completed. Has anyone else figured out how to get these details?

Answer (score 0):

The result is returned as a `RavenJToken` in `WaitForCompletion`.

```
var result = op.WaitForCompletion();
```

The documentation isn't clear on this.

Hint: When I can't find examples in the documentation I look at the [RavenDB source code](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb) unit tests [for examples](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=retrievedetails), e.g. the [ShouldRetrieveOperationDetailsWhenTheyWereRequested](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/ca822bdfd0c2b2c0a7dc46807776bd3dd3b580c6/Raven.Tests.Issues/RavenDB_2936.cs#L118) unit test.

Comment: the unit test you link to is virtually useless in explaining what the `RavenJToken` contains and how to use it, since it simply asserts that the result is not null